# R best practices: do I need to "unset" a RefClass?

Tags: r

**BLUP: What are the risks of creating an environment whose parent is .GlobalEnv, and calling setRefClass within this environment?**

I have a package ([repository on Github](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/hdfqlr)) that loads the contents of an R file provided by HDFql. This wrapper contains a [call to setRefClass](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/hdfqlr/blob/81d3d61daf408438634bf6676cc7944b3f609e67/HDFql-mod.R#L226). After trying a lot of different things (most of which failed) I settled on sourcing the wrapper into an environment that is a child of `.GlobalEnv`. The environment itself lives in an environment contained in the package. This nesting was required to get around `binding` errors, because the call to setRefClass fails if it is executed inside an environment whose ancestor is the package namespace. The global environment seemed to be the only environment suitable for the `setRefClass` evaluation.

However, I'm a bit worried about creating and using an environment in a package whose parent is `.GlobalEnv`, and making calls to `setRefClass` inside this environment. **What are potential pitfalls when doing this? Are there best practices for removing or "unsetting" the RefClass when finished? Is there a better solution I am not thinking of?**

I have included some sample code below, although it is not reproducible; if you want a reproducible example, you can clone the package repository and/or install it with `devtools`. The code in question lives in the function `hql_load()` in file `connect.r`.

```r
# "hql" is an empty environment exported by the package
constants = new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
source(constants.file, local = constants)
assign("constants", constants, envir = hql)
```

where `constants.file` contains the code

```r
hdfql_cursor_ <- setRefClass("hdfql_cursor_", 
  field = list(address = "numeric"), 
  method = list(
    finalize = function(){
      .Call("_hdfql_cursor_destroy", .self$address, PACKAGE = "HDFqlR")
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: I decided to use `.BaseNamespaceEnv` instead of `.GlobalEnv` since I presume it is a better choice, but I don't know if this really makes a difference.

Comment: Update: using `.BaseNamespaceEnv` does not work because calls to `package:methods` don't work when you `attach` the `constants` environment and try to create new instance of the class. Guess I'll stick with `globalenv()`.